# Is privacy part of the CIA triad or an independent concept?

Tags: encryption, network, privacy

I am a bit confused between the CIA triad and privacy. Are these two concepts independent? If yes, it seems to me that privacy can be part of the CIA triad.

Comment: The CIA triad helps in achieving privacy. If you want your data to be private, you use confidentiality. However, CIA triad doesn't stop someone from seeing that a connection is being made. So collecting metadata is still possible. Thus complete privacy is not guaranteed by CIA triad.

Answer (score 1):

In the CIA triad, privacy is often seen as equal to (or part of) the **confidentiality** concept.

> Roughly synonymous with privacy as a security concern is the Confidentiality part of the CIA Triad.

[(Source)](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/the-cia-triad/)

However, you can also relate privacy to the **entire CIA triad**, as an overall goal:

> Privacy relates to all elements of the CIA triad. It considers which
>   information can be shared with others (confidentiality), how that
>   information can be accessed safely (integrity), and how it can be
>   accessed (availability).

[(Source)](http://www.pearsonitcertification.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30287&seqNum=2)

Privacy often refers to individuals and what of their personal data is collected/shared, while confidentiality is about protecting the access to the data. If an attacker manages to download the customer database of a webshop, the system failed to provide **confidentiality** -- and in consequence, the leak of addresses and phone numbers compromises the **privacy** of their customers.

Also see: [What is the difference between privacy, confidentiality and security?](https://www.techopedia.com/7/29803/security/what-is-the-difference-between-privacy-confidentiality-and-security)